Generating Color Shades based on contourLine elevation
I am working on a program, that is able to generate landmasses and mountains with contour lines. I would like to distinguish each contour line with a separate shade of particular color, say:

Green 0-15 (LowLands)
WheatYellow 16-30 (MidLands)
Brown 31-40 (HighLands)
SnowWhite 41-50 (MountainTops)

I tried several attitudes, one of them is this piece of code I found on this website
public static Color[] GetColorShades(Color baseColor, int shadesCount)
{
    shadesCount *= 2;
    Color[] output = new Color[shadesCount];
    for (int index = 0; index < shadesCount; index++)
    {
        output[index] = DarkenColor(baseColor, (double)index / (double)shadesCount);
    }
    return output;
}

private static Color DarkenColor(Color color, double fraction)
{
    int red = (int)Math.Round(Math.Max(0, color.R - 255 * fraction));
    int green = (int)Math.Round(Math.Max(0, color.G - 255 * fraction));
    int blue = (int)Math.Round(Math.Max(0, color.B - 255 * fraction));
    return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
}

This code works fine for green color. but for some reason fails to generate color shades of yellow and brown. White also seems to be a problem.
Is anyone able to help me with an algorhitm that would split a number that defines height maximum to four groups, each with shades of a particular color? See image for inspiration
This is how it works with strictly defined hexadecimal color codes:

This is what I get when I apply algorithm above:


Your "darkening" code is probably not correct, it will modify both the hue and luminance at the same time. You might want to use Hue-Saturation-Value or Hue-Saturation-Lightness, since these tend to better match our intuitive understanding of color. That way you could simply modify the L or V component if you want a darker shade of the same color.
Another alternative would be to define two colors for each band, and just interpolate between them:
public static IEnumerable<Color> CreateInterpolatedShades(Color x, Color y, int count) =>
      Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => Lerp(x, y, i / (float)count));
public static Color Lerp(this Color x, Color y, float v)
{
    var vInv = 1 - v;
    var r = (int)(x.R * vInv + y.R * v);
    var g = (int)(x.G * vInv + y.G * v);
    var b = (int)(x.B * vInv + y.B * v);
    var a = (int)(x.A * vInv + y.A * v);
    // Clamp to 0-255
    r = r < 0 ? 0 : r > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue : r;
    g = g < 0 ? 0 : g > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue : g;
    b = b < 0 ? 0 : b > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue : b;
    a = a < 0 ? 0 : a > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue : a;
    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}

This should work well if the interpolated colors are fairly close.

Thanks, Ill try it out and let you know soon
